# Looking for an error in VBA-Excel Data validation code

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a entry data checking vba-code and this is what i got so far. The code is supposed to mark values that are out of range and throw an error when the wrong datatype is entered. Right now the code throws an error for every entry in the table even if it is in range. I do not find the problem though. Does anyone now where I made a mistake?

```
Sub CheckColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long
Dim DblWidthMax As Double
Dim DblHeightMax As Double
Dim DblLengthMin As Double
Dim DblWidthMin As Double
Dim DblHeightMin As Double
Dim DblLengthMax As Double


DblLenghtMax = 20000
DblWidthMax = 20000
DblHeightMax = 20000
DblLengthMin = 5
DblWidthMin = 5
DblHeightMin = 5

    lCol = Range("C2").End(xlToRight).Column
    lRow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each rng In Range("C2", Cells(lRow, lCol))
        If IsNumeric(rng) = False Then
          MsgBox ("A number has to be entered " & "Row " & rng.Row 
          & " Column " & rng.Column)
          rng.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

       If rng.Value > DblLengthMax Or rng.Value < DblLengthMin Then
         MsgBox ("Value in " & "Row " & rng.Row & " Column " & 
         rng.Column & " is out of range. Check for unit (mm)")
         rng.Font.ColorIndex = 46
        
      End If

    Next rng

End Sub
```

So for example I enter the values: 3000, 50, 3. for length width and height. Since my range is 5 to 20000 the first two values should be in Range and not be colored. Right now every value is colored orange. I would only expect the 3 to be coloured

[image]

Comment: Can you post a data example and expected output?

Comment: Because `DblLenghtMin` is spelt differently in your declarations and initial value setting to the version in your if statement (`DblLengthMin`).

Comment: @JosWoolley thank you! I fixed it, unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: It did for me when I tested. I trust you made sure that all **three** occurrences of that name are now the same?

Comment: I checked and it doesn't work still. I posted an example of enry data and the output in the text. @JosWoolley

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I added an example in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables have not been properly declared. As example, you have

`Dim DblLengthMax As Double`

But then you do:

`DblLenghtMax = 20000`

Notice **is not the same** variable!!!! So `DblLengthMax` is initialized as 0. Then your code does:

`If rng.Value > DblLengthMax Or rng.Value < DblLengthMin Then` but remember because of your typo `DblLengthMax=0` so any value greater than 0 will be colored...

**ALWAYS** use `Option Explicit` command to avoid these errors and typos:

> [Option Explicit
> statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement)

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long
Dim DblWidthMax As Double
Dim DblHeightMax As Double
Dim DblLengthMin As Double
Dim DblWidthMin As Double
Dim DblHeightMin As Double
Dim DblLengthMax As Double


DblLengthMax = 20000
DblWidthMax = 20000
DblHeightMax = 20000
DblLengthMin = 5
DblWidthMin = 5
DblHeightMin = 5

    lCol = Range("C2").End(xlToRight).Column
    lRow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each rng In Range("C2", Cells(lRow, lCol))
        If IsNumeric(rng) = False Then
          MsgBox ("A number has to be entered " & "Row " & rng.Row & " Column " & rng.Column)
          rng.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

       If rng.Value > DblLengthMax Or rng.Value < DblLengthMin Then
         MsgBox ("Value in " & "Row " & rng.Row & " Column " & rng.Column & " is out of range. Check for unit (mm)")
         rng.Font.ColorIndex = 46
        
      End If

    Next rng
End Sub
```

[image]